# Evaluating $\int _0^{\infty }W\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lambert-w

How can i evaluate $\displaystyle\int _0^{\infty }W\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x$ in an easy manner i managed to end up with this
$$3\int _0^{\infty }\frac{W\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)}{W\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)+1}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
But how can i continue?.

$W(x)$ is the lambert w function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generalize this integral
$$\underbrace{\int _0^{\infty }W\left(\frac{1}{x^n}\right)\:dx}_{t=W\left(\frac{1}{x^n}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\int _0^{\infty }t^{1-\frac{1}{n}}e^{-\frac{t}{n}}\:dt+\frac{1}{n}\int _0^{\infty }t^{-\frac{1}{n}}e^{-\frac{t}{n}}\:dt=n^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\Gamma \left(2-\frac{1}{n}\right)+n^{-\frac{1}{n}}\Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$=-n^{-\frac{1}{n}}\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
So
$$\boxed{\int _0^{\infty }W\left(\frac{1}{x^n}\right)\:dx=-n^{-\frac{1}{n}}\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$
So for your integral, letting $n=3$ gets
$$\int _0^{\infty }W\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\:dx=-3^{-\frac{1}{3}}\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)=3^{\frac{2}{3}}\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\approx2.816678$$